# Please update the Markdown help to include how to enter keyboard symbols

Tags: feature-request

The how-to and copy-and-paste codes for entering keyboard symbols is [scattered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys) [around](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/21703) AD [meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/210/21703) but it is something that comes up a lot and is very helpful, particularly when using an iPad.

Can we please get these answers consolidated and added to the [full page Markdown help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help)?  If not the full info itself, then at least links to it, like was done for [inline HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/183358).

I know that technically `<kbd>` is HTML but obviously not a lot of people know it, so just using it as an example of inline HTML is not enough.

Comment: I'll look into if this is something we can change, but I presume this is a site-wide control. If so - we'll move this to the site wide meta for discussion there. Consider up voting this related question if you feel icons would also help you out. http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390/editor-button-or-shortcut-for-kbd-tag

Comment: @bmike if this is a site-wide (i.e. *all* stackexhange sites) control, then changing it would also unlock the functionality of markup-related icons. Are there any other sites that could use this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a *Markdown* help page is an appropriate place for teaching users about HTML tags, however obscure they may be.

I see three options:

- Don't provide a Markdown help page. Provide an *editing* help page that covers both Markdown and HTML.
- Provide a discoverable [editor button](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390/editor-button-or-shortcut-for-kbd-tag) for inserting the `<kbd>` tag.
- Polish and link more prominently to an [HTML help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).